# Python list slicing with string argument

Tags: python

It's possible to slice a python list like this:

```
>>> list=['a', 'b']
>>> list[0:1]
['a']
```

However, when passing the index as a string, an error is thrown:

```
>>> index="0:1"
>>> list[index]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How can I specify a list index as a string? What data type is `0:1` in `list[0:1]`, really?

Comment: You should use two integers as the start and stop indexes and then use those.

Comment: As you can see from the traceback, "list indices must be integers, not str"

Answer (score 8):

`n:m` is syntactic sugar for a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). You could `split` your index string, convert its parts to integers, and create a `slice` from those.

```
>>> lst = list(range(10))
>>> index = "1:4"
>>> s = slice(*map(int, index.split(':')))
>>> lst[s]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Works just the same with three parts:

```
>>> index = "1:9:2"
>>> s = slice(*map(int, index.split(':')))
>>> lst[s]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

If you want to allow for "blank" parts, the conversion gets a little bit more involved:

```
>>> index = "::-1"
>>> s = slice(*[int(x) if x else None for x in index.split(':')])
>>> lst[s]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680826/python-create-slice-object-from-string

Comment: @tobias_k...slicing a `range` will produce a `range` and not a `list` in Python3, correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @IronFist You are right, tried this in Python2; converted to `list` so it works with both.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just convert your *slicing* string into integers by splitting on `:`, and then using them as slicing indices.

```
list=['a', 'b']
slicer_str = '0:1'
slicer_int = [int(i) for i in slicer_str.split(':')]
print(list[slicer_int[0]:slicer_int[1]])
```

Comment: What would happen to a `slicer_str` of `:` or `:1` in this case?

Comment: @Zulakis if such slicer happens to come in your case, you can use map and slice, as suggested by tobias_k. That will handle all such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec()` for this.

```
l = ['a', 'b']
index="0:1"
exec('print(l[{}])'.format(index))
```

The print is needed only to see the output. You can assign it to a variable and call the variable afterwards instead.

Comment: Without the `print`, i.e. to assign the result to some variable, you should use `eval` instead of `exec`. Also, never use `eval` (or `exec`) if it can be helped.

Comment: `exec('a = l[{}]'.format(index))` would assign to `a` as well

Comment: Right, but this way you could not wrap the ugly exec/eval part into a function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in this particular case, there are no functions involved. In theory you can make a as global in exec() and carry it over even inside a function, it would be super ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ : ] where you specify the start point and end point ,so you can easily trace what you intend to slice

Comment: I believe the above answer is not appropriate for the question asked. The comments provided by Mark, etc. are sufficient for problem resolution.